# Como invocar função no primeiro clique do botão e outra no segundo clique

Tags: javascript, jquery, condição, onclick

Como faço para a primeira função ser chamada dentro do primeiro clique do botão, pelo *evento* `ondblclick();` e a segunda função no segundo clique do mesmo botão.

Imagino invocar a função do primeiro clique no botao e outra no segundo clique, tipo assim:

observe como deve ser:

```
function a(){
   ...
declaração 
   ...
}
function b(){
   ...
declaração
   ...
}
```

Ja no botão, algo como:

```
<button ondblclick="a();?:b();">2-in-1</button>
```

É simples pra quem sabe manipular `?:`, o mesmo de `if .. else`, só que de fórmula minúscula e apropriada para esta idéia.

Agradeço desde ja, ajuda de todos.

Comment: Como assim, tu pergunta e posta a solução? é dessa forma mesmo, se não funcionou, deve haver outro problema ....

Comment: acredito que o que ele dizer é no primeiro click uma função, no segundo outra. No ondbl se eu nao me engano ele faz a função (se tiver mais de uma ele faz junto) com 2 clicks, estou errado ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, não sei se essa é a melhor prática, mas funcionou para mim

## JQuery

```js
var cont = 0;
$( "#teste" ).click(function() {  
    if(cont == 0)
      {
     a();
      cont += 1;
      }
  else
      {
      b();
      cont = 0;
      }
});

function a(){
 alert('aqui');
}

function b(){
 alert('aqui 2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="teste">
teste
</a>
```

Agora transcrição para:

## JavaScript

```js
var cont = 0;

document.getElementById( "teste" ).onclick = function() {  
if(cont == 0)
{
a();
cont += 1;
}
else
{
b();
cont = 0;
}
}

function a(){
alert('função A');
}

function b(){
alert('função B');
}
```

```html
<button id="teste">Clique-e-Descomplique</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

make sure the "script" is after the "body", put
so that the code in js is executed after creating the html, otherwise the "onclick" will not exist and will return null generating an error.

```
<html>
  <head><head>
  <body></body>
  **<script></script>**
</html>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua resposta? Caso prefira, você também pode responder perguntas em  língua inglesa no [site em inglês do Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).